# How to fix issue with MSBuild directory?

Tags: xamarin.android, msbuild

I tried to set up the most recent android sdks for my android project and since then I've been getting this build error:

`Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1668, 2): [APT0000] invalid resource directory name: /Users/myname/rotogrinders-xamarin/myApp.Android/obj/Debug/res/ users " users".`

What can i do to resolve this?

Comment: Can you double check that your Build Tools version inside your Android SDK is >= 26.0.0? Can you also get me a Diagnostic Build Output?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

Comment: You can check the required build tools version in yourapp.Android/obj/debug/[compile-version]/build.props

Comment: @JessieZhang the build tools version is 28.0.3

Comment: it seems like the issue is with the space in the " users" portion of the path, but im not sure how to edit that.

Comment: When you create folder, if there are Spaces, it will prompt an error, and will not create successfully.This should not be the case.

Comment: Since we couldn't reproduce this question,  could you please share a basic demo so that we can test with it?

Comment: I tried to add a Resource to a shared project. when i deleted it the issue was resolved

Comment: What resource are you adding, and what is the name?And is this resource added to  `user` directory?